# Cannot navigate back in Azure Active Directory Graph API when using filter

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am facing below issue in azure active directory, When I didn't include any filter in Graph API query I can navigate back to the previous page using  `previous-page=true`but when I include `$filter` in query back navigation doesn't work. How to solve this issue?

**Working Query**

```
https://graph.windows.net/GraphDir1.onMicrosoft.com/users?&api-version=1.6&$top=8&$skiptoken=X'44537074020000253A37646432326566376132404772617068446972312E6F6E6D6963726F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F66323238316233622D663432642D346161642D616361612D38653064633438336163653600213A414155736572406772617068646972312E6F6E4D6963726F736F66742E636F6D29557365725F62393733333834392D633038372D346330622D626466362D656330393935356262343739B900000000000000000000'&previous-page=true
```

**Not Working Query**

```
https://graph.windows.net/GraphDir1.onMicrosoft.com/users?&api-version=1.6&$top=8&$filter=startswith(displayName,'s')%20or%20startswith(userPrincipalName,'s')%20or%20startswith(mailNickname,'s')&$skiptoken=X'445370740600000000000000000000100000008EA617921A2C7B46895AE95405BD556E000000000000000000000017312E322E3834302E3131333535362E312E342E32333331'&previous-page=true
```

When I use back navigation with `$filter` query, I am getting below response:

```
Error: 400 - Bad Request
 See Response Headers for details.
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Invalid previous page search request."}}}
```

Any Solution for this?

Comment: I am also facing this error but query with filter works fine when we do forward navigation but it fails only when we append 'previous-page=true' key in query string.